# CSS Logged in User not recognised

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

This code does not recognise a logged in User on my database. I've tried several things, none of which so far have affected anything. Can Someone point out the error(s)

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 include("dbconnect.php");
 $numrows=0;
 $sqlMember = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Membership_Number"]);
$sqlPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Password"]); 

 $query="SELECT First_name, Last_name, Membership_Number FROM members WHERE Membership_Number='$member' AND Password='$password'";


 $link = mysql_query($query);
 if (!$link) {
  die('login error');
 }
 $numrows=mysql_num_rows($link);
 if ($numrows>0){  // authentication is successfull
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query));
  $_SESSION['user']['first_name']=$row['first_name'];
  $_SESSION['user']['last_name']=$row['last_name'];
  $_SESSION['user']['Membership_Number ']=$row['Membership_Number '];
  echo $_SESSION['user']['fname'].' '.$_SESSION['user']['lname'];
  header("location:members_area.php");
 } else {
  header("location:../invalid.php");  // authentication was unsuccessfull
 }
?>
```

HTML

```
<form id="jjjj" action="Send_log_details.php" class="register" method="POST">
        <ul>
        <li>
        Membership Number:<br>
        <input type="text" id="Membership_Number" name="Membership_Number">
        </li>
        <li>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password"  id="Password" name="Password" value="Log in">
        </li>
        <li>

        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Login" onclick="logMeIn()">             
        </li>
        </ul>
        </form>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: CSS has nothing to do with sessions. Please specify a more sensible question.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: You need advanced CSS query for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MySQL Login issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281696/php-mysql-login-issue)

Answer (score 1):

you have `$link` variable containing MYSQL query and you are using `$query` variable.

```
if ($numrows>0){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($link)) {
      $_SESSION['user']['first_name']=$row['first_name'];
      $_SESSION['user']['last_name']=$row['last_name'];
      $_SESSION['user']['Membership_Number']=$row['Membership_Number'];
  }
  echo $_SESSION['user']['fname'].' '.$_SESSION['user']['lname'];
  header("Location: members_area.php");

 } else {
  header("Location: ../invalid.php");
 }
```

Comment: an error appears in this line 

} else {

Comment: I'm afraid this does still not work, is there anywhere else I may be going wrong

Comment: @RichardJess don't be too quick. First learn and then script or code. here is the starting tutorials for you. When I was beginner, i had this type of issues. i think you need a good start. So, http://phpeasystep.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Could the this line be the problem:

```
$_SESSION['user']['Membership_Number ']=$row['Membership_Number '];
```

It should be:

```
$_SESSION['user']['Membership_Number']=$row['Membership_Number'];
```

I have removed the space from the end of the array key name.

Comment: well, i already had done that in my answer :D

Comment: @AspiringAqib: Oh yes, beat me to it. you missed the first one though.